# Access tabs of the same website from Chrome extension without using the "tabs" permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a window manager extension for Google Chrome, the extension is supposed to work only on a specific website.

I need to list all the open tabs of the given website, and to do so I do:

```js
chrome.windows.getAll(windows => {
  windows.forEach(window => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: window.id }, tabs => {
      const websiteTabs = tabs.filter(tab => tab.url.startsWith(MY_WEBSITE));
      console.log(websiteTabs);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that to make the above code work I need to access `tab.url`, which requires the `tabs` permission, that in turn shows to the users that install my extension a warning that says my extension can access their **browser history**.

How can I get the above code work without needing the `tabs` permission so that my users are not concerned about their privacy?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way, I'm not sure if there's a better system but this one works.

Basically I send a message to each tab, and I tell my website tabs to respond with their URL, this way I only receive responses from my own website tabs.

```js
// background.js
chrome.windows.getAll(windows => {
  windows.forEach(window => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: window.id }, tabs => {
      tabs.forEach(tab => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          tab.id,
          { message: 'whois', id: tab.id },
          url => {
            console.log('This is the tab URL!', url);
          }
        );
      });
      const websiteTabs = tabs.filter(tab => tab.url.startsWith(MY_WEBSITE));
    });
  });
});

// inject.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if(request.message === 'whois') {
    sendResponse(window.location.href);
  }
});
```